# Finding Top Word Count in .txt file - while loop going extremely slow and not working properly

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, text-files

**I'm trying to essentially iterate through every word in the .txt file and when I find a word (from my words map) with more than the maxwordcount variable I add it into the front of the topwords vector**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    fstream txtfile;
    string filename = argv[1];
    string word, tempword;
    int maxwordcount = 0;
    int wordcount = 0;
    int uniquewordcount = 0;
    vector<pair <string, int> > topwords;
    map<string, int> words;

if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "Incorrect number of arguments on the command line bud" << endl;
}else{
    txtfile.open(filename.c_str());
if (txtfile.is_open()) {
        while (txtfile >> word){
            //removePunctuation(word);
            //transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), [](unsigned char c){ return::tolower(c); });     //makes string lowercase using iterator
            if (words.find(word) == words.end()) {   
                words[word] = 1;                                //adds word into the map as a pair starting with a word count of 1
                if (words[word] > maxwordcount) {            //For case if word is the first word added to the map
                    maxwordcount = words[word];              //change maxwordcount
                    topwords.insert( topwords.begin(), make_pair(word, words[word]) );    //insert word into the front of the top words vector
                    cout << "word: '" << word << "'  word-count: " << words[word] << endl;
                }
                uniquewordcount++;              
            }else{                                          //the word is found
                words[word]++;                              //increment count for word by 1
                if (words[word] > maxwordcount) {           //check if wordcount > maxwordcount
                    topwords.insert( topwords.begin(), make_pair(word, words[word]) );      //insert word into the front of the top words vector       
                }                                           
            }
            wordcount++;
        }
```

At the end of the program I want to display top 10 or so words from the txt file.  I tested whether the while loop was running by displaying a live wordcount (cout).  The number was going up, but it was going up extremely slow.  Also I'm using huge books for my txt files.

[Image of results when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUl1u.png)

I also don't completely understand inserting variables into maps and vectors, so something might be going wrong there.

I've hit a dead-end, so anything will help at this point.

I used a smaller text file too to test:

```
This is a small sentence to test test test
hey hey
```

Results:

```
word: 'This'  word-count: 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
7
7
8
8
There were 11 words in the file.
There were 8 unique words in the file.
Top 20 words in little.txt:
   hey 2
   test 3
   test 2
   This 1
Segmentation fault
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't have a clue where to look next or what to test.  Still an amateur at C++ and C too.

Comment: did you try using a smaller file, say eg with 5 words?

Comment: I don't think your algorithm works: if your file starts with a 100 words "x", and no other words are repeated a 100 times, your `topwords` would only contain references to that word "x". Look up `max heap`

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that all of the text files I use for this are pretty much books full of tons of different words.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program on your terms, instruction by instruction if you need to get that low, and watch what happens as it happens. Typical usage is to start with coarse steps, looking at the function level for the program to do something unexpected. When it does, you've probably found a bug and need to narrow in on it. Restart the program and advance to the function and this time step into the function. Keep looking deeper and deeper until you understand the sequence of events that lead up to the bug. Then strike off its head.

Comment: Try `unordered_map` instead of `map`.  It's made to be faster when you're dealing with huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

you should read the file by lines, process line by line

read file file by line: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-process-a-file-line-by-line-in-c/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-sentence-into-words-in-cpp/

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_functions.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_function_param.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_function_return.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_pointers.asp <--- very importend

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_references.asp <--- likewise importend

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


vector<std::pair <string, int> > topwords;

void store(vector<pair <string, int> > &topwords, string str){
    auto pos = std::find_if(topwords.begin(), topwords.end(),
                            [str](std::pair<string, int> const &b) {
            return b.first == str;
});
    
    //std::cout<< pos->first << endl;
    
    if(pos != topwords.end()){
        std::cout << "word: " << pos->first << " " << pos->second << " found" << endl;
        pos->second++;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "not found" << endl;
        topwords.push_back( make_pair(str,1) );
    }
}

void removeDupWord(string str)
{
    // Used to split string around spaces.
    istringstream ss(str);
    
    // Traverse through all words
    /*
    do {
        // Read a word
        string word;
        ss >> word;
        
        // Print the read word
        cout << word << endl;
        store(topwords, word );
        
        // While there is more to read
    } while (ss);
    */
    string word;
    while (ss >> word) {
        //cout << word << endl;
        const std::regex sanitized{ R"([-[\]{}()*+?.,\^$|#\s])" };
        
        std::stringstream result;
        std::regex_replace(std::ostream_iterator<char>(result), word.begin(), word.end(), sanitized, "");
        
        //store(topwords, word );
        store(topwords, result.str() );
    }
}

void readReadFile(string &fileName){
    std::cout << "fileName" << fileName << endl;
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str)) {
        //std::cout << str << "\n";
        removeDupWord(str);
        //store(topwords, str);
    }
}

bool compareFunction (const std::pair<std::string, int> &a, const std::pair<std::string, int> &b) {
    
    return a.first<b.first; // sort by letter
}

bool compareFunction2 (const std::pair<std::string, int> &a, const std::pair<std::string, int> &b) {
    
    return a.second>b.second; // sort by count
}

bool cmp(pair<string, int> &A, pair<string, int> &B) {
    return A.second < B.second;
}

void check(vector<pair <string, int> > &topwords){
    std::pair<string, int> mostUsedWord = make_pair("",0);
    for(auto ii : topwords){
        std::cout << "word: " << ii.first << " count: " << ii.second << endl;
        if(ii.second > mostUsedWord.second){
            mostUsedWord.first = ii.first;
            mostUsedWord.second = ii.second;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "most used Word: " << mostUsedWord.first << " x " << mostUsedWord.second << " Times." << endl;
           
}

void get_higestTopTenValues(vector<pair <string, int> > &topwords){
    std::sort(topwords.begin(),topwords.end(),compareFunction2);//sort the vector by count
    int MAX = std::max_element(topwords.begin(), topwords.end(), cmp)->second;
    std::cout << "max: " << MAX << endl;
    for(auto ii : topwords){
        //std::cout << "word: " << ii.first << " count: " << ii.second << endl;
        if(ii.second >= (MAX - 10)){
            std::cout << ii.first << " " << ii.second << endl;
            
        }
    }
}

void get_LowestTopTenValues(vector<pair <string, int> > &topwords){
    std::sort(topwords.begin(),topwords.end(),compareFunction2);//sort the vector by count
    int MIN = std::min_element(topwords.begin(), topwords.end(), cmp)->second;
    std::cout << "min: " << MIN << endl;
    for(auto ii : topwords){
        //std::cout << "word: " << ii.first << " count: " << ii.second << endl;
        if(ii.second <= (MIN + 9)){
            std::cout << ii.first << " " << ii.second << endl;
            
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::string word, fileName;
    
    fileName = "input.txt";
    readReadFile(fileName);
    
    topwords.push_back( make_pair("ba",1) );
    topwords.push_back( make_pair("bu",1) );
    topwords.push_back( make_pair("hmmm",1) );
    topwords.push_back( make_pair("what",1) );
    topwords.push_back( make_pair("and",1) );
    topwords.push_back( make_pair("hello",1) );
    
    word = "hellos";
    
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    
    word = "hello";
    
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    store(topwords, word);
    
    std::sort(topwords.begin(),topwords.end(),compareFunction);//sort the vector by letter
    // or
    //std::sort(topwords.begin(),topwords.end(),compareFunction2);//sort the vector by count
    
    
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    std::cout << " get all values" << endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    check(topwords);
    
    
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    std::cout << " get the top 10 highest values" << endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    get_higestTopTenValues(topwords);
    
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    std::cout << " get the top 10 lowest values" << endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    get_LowestTopTenValues(topwords);
    
}
```

Comment: I actually have an iteration of the project where I do this, but that makes it difficult for me to constantly check every word without doing a bunch of splitting, etc.  I used the algorithm library to do that.  But good looking out!

Comment: http://cpp.sh/9eh4e <---- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-sentence-into-words-in-cpp/
this code will brake up a string, so you can easily add them to your vector of pairs or increase the counter value if the word already exist in your vector.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/8euv < ---- you might like the third option from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-sentence-into-words-in-cpp/ more

Answer (score 0):

This question has his been aswered long time ago. I stumbled over the question and asnwer and I find everything overly complicated.

Therefore I would like to add a more modern C++ solution making use of existing STL elements.

This makes the code more compact.

Please see below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

const std::string fileName{"r:\\loremipsum.txt"};

int main() {

    if (std::ifstream textFileStream{ fileName }; textFileStream) {

        // Here we store the count of all words
        std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> counter{};

        size_t countOfOverallWords{}; // Counter for the number of all words

        // Read all words from file, remove punctuation, and count teh occurence
        for (std::string word; textFileStream >> word; counter[word]++) {
            word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ispunct), word.end());
            ++countOfOverallWords;
        }
        // For storing the top 10
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> top(10);

        // Get top 10
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), top.begin(), top.end(),
            [](const std::pair<std::string, size_t >& p1, const std::pair<std::string, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

        // Now show result
        std::cout << "Count of overall words:\t " << countOfOverallWords << "\nCount of unique words:\t " << counter.size() << "\n\nTop 10:\n";
        for (const auto& t : top) std::cout << "Value: " << t.first << "\t Count: " << t.second << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open source file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2.

Additionally compiled and tested with clang11.0 and gcc10.2 with flags `--std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`

Language: C++17